# Ошибка "Неявное преобразование типа "string" в "int" невозможно"

Tags: c#, преобразование-типов

```
this.button13.Click += new EventHandler(button13_Click);
{
    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    int a = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Ошибка:

> Неявное преобразование типа "string" в "int" невозможно

Comment: И в чём проблема? Так не пытайтесь присваивать числу строку.. делов-то. Вам даже подсказка: код читается прямо по-человечески: инт а равно текст. Ясное же дело, что это невозможно.

Comment: меня одного смущает, что вы пытаетесь пустую(!) строку в число преобразовать? даже не зная класса ``Convert``, пытаться сделать такое с точки зрения логики глупо.

Comment: @sasha_plakh: А какое это имеет отношение к данному вопросу?

Answer (score 3):

[Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

Comment: а куда этот код дописать? извини я новичок

Comment: Тогда самое время научиться. Надо взять эту функцию и использовать её чтобы превратить текст в число. Ну же, думайте, думайте. Не ищите готовых рецептов, а то 100% ничего путного не выйдет. Возможно даже стоит оставить C# в покое и взяться за старый добрый паскаль и учиться по старым "школьным" урокам по информатике по паскалю.

Comment: паскаль и дельфи знаю, но хочу уже перейти к c# только не знаю с чего начать, скачал 10 книг, но ни в одном там в доступном языке нет, сам так тоже ищу статьи в гугле интересующих меня вопросов

Comment: вот c# с азов [simple-cs.ru][1]


  [1]: http://simple-cs.ru

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так

```
textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

Это немного проще чем Парсить.

Comment: да, я так же и сделал уже, так удобнее, спасибо.
У меня тут последняя проблемка осталась, я вот создаю калькулятор, все сделал, так:
ввожу число нажимаю например на "+" все исчезает, запоминаю это число при этом, ввожу еще одно число, но щас я не знаю как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на "=" он ввел мне ответ, просто он будет в таком случае путать операции и выводить все или же ничего, можешь дать мне подсказку как поступить?

Comment: Т.е у вас 1 TextBox, при вводе первого числа и нажатии на + у вас все исчезает при этом число сохраняется в переменную, а при нажатии на = он вам выводит 1 переменная + 2 переменная... я правильно вас понял?

Не легче ли сделать 2 TextBox'a и уже таким образом делать калькулятор.. а не все в одном. Если вы пойдете 2-м путем, то я смогу вам помочь, а первым нет :( Т.к ты и я новички предлагаю изучать C# вместе... напиши мне Jack-Sparrou@yandex.ru, дальше перейдем на скайп :)

Answer (score 0):

> да, я так же и сделал уже, так удобнее, спасибо. У меня тут последняя проблемка осталась, я вот создаю калькулятор, все сделал, так: ввожу число нажимаю например на "+" все исчезает, запоминаю это число при этом, ввожу еще одно число, но щас я не знаю как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на "=" он ввел мне ответ, просто он будет в таком случае путать операции и выводить все или же ничего, можешь дать мне подсказку как поступить?

Сохраняешь первое значение в переменной-члене класса при нажатии "+", при нажатии "=" прибавляешь к нему текущее значение, прочитанное из текстбокса при помощи `int.Parse(textBox1.Text);` или `Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`. Записываешь в текстбокс полученное число, переведённое в строку.