# Неявное преобразование типа "string" в "int" невозможно

Tags: c#

```
string url = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
string l = url.Split('#')[**l**];
if (l[0] == 'a'){
    Settings1.Default.token = l.Split('&')[0].Split('=')[1];
    Settings1.Default.id = l.Split('=')[3];
    Settings1.Default.auth = true;
    MessageBox.Show(Settings1.Default.token **+** - - **+** Settings1.Default.id);
    this.Close();
}
```

2 ошибки вылазят:
Ошибка  1   Неявное преобразование типа "string" в "int" невозможно
Ошибка  2   Оператор "+" не может применяться к операнду типа "string"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где исправить косяк

Comment: спасибо огромное! с классом получилось.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: «[Ошибка “Неявное преобразование типа ”string“ в ”int“ невозможно”](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/57988/208074)».

Answer (score 3):

- `url.Split('#')[**l**];` - это некорректный синтаксис. Индекс для массива должен быть целым числом.
- `Settings1.Default.token **+** - - **+** Settings1.Default.id` - снова неправильный синтаксис. Непонятно, что вы хотите сделать.
- Не нужно вручную разбирать url, используйте класс [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.uri.aspx) и его свойства. Например: `webBrowser1.Url.Fragment`